# how to start code server terminal with chroot?

Tags: vscode-remote, termux, code-server

I have a code server that runs on Android with termux, for university reasons, there are times when I must share my vscode environment and I would not like to expose my entire system and personal files through the terminal.

So I was wondering if it was possible to expose a terminal from an alpine distro with chroot (prrot in the case of termux) by default every time code server opens a terminal

Answer (score 0):

After some time reading the vscode config, I realized that you can use the shell option to force it to start inside with alpine and not expose my files, nor my android system with termux

"terminal.integrated.shell.linux":"/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/startalpine"

[image: Chroot alpine terminal by default]